# Blackberry Access App fails to open Camera in Android for scanning Barcode

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-dynamics

Blackberry Access (v3.3.0) fails to open Camera in Android. I am using ZXing library for barcode which returns error saying "DOM Exception: Permission Denied". I checked the known issue list of Blackberry Access for version 3.3, it mentions about similar issue but the given workaround is not working for me.
This works fine in Blackberry Access for windows and IOS.

Could you please help me with the solution or provide me an ETA about when this issue gets resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You could be restricted by the configuration of the BlackBerry Access application configuration.  You can view this in BlackBerry UEM by:

1. Log into the BlackBerry UEM Admin console.
2. Click on Apps on the left menu.
3. Choose BlackBerry Access.
4. Click on the App configuration being used.
5. On the General tab, verify if "Enable QR Code Scanning" is unchecked.
6. On the Features tab, verify if the option to allow a user to take photos to upload is checked.

The known issue I think you are referring too (GMAGDAND-11052) is different than what you describe. In that issue, the Camera may stop responding if the user opens the camera to scan a QR code, waits for the idle timeout of the app to lock and then unlocks the app.  At this point the Camera may not respond. The workaround is to restart BlackBerry Access.

Comment: Appreciate quick turn around. I checked and tried your steps, that didn't worked for me. I faced same issue with IOS, which is resolved by checking "Allow WebRTC" option. Was wondering do we have similar setup in BlackBerry Access Configuration for Android? I am using zxing which tries to open camera using video element which is then scanned and returns the result.

Comment: WebRTC is not currently supported on BlackBerry Access on Android.

Comment: Could you guide me which java script library / plugin should I use to make it work with blackberry access ?